# Unable to compare lines read from txt file using Scanner in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I am trying write code which will read input from a txt file and stop after reaching a certain line.

This is my current code:

```
File data = new File("text.txt");
try {

    Scanner load = new Scanner(data);

    while (load.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = load.nextLine();
        if (line == "end") break;
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    load.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

This is the text contained in `text.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
end
line5
line6
```

I expected it to only output the lines before the line `end`, but instead, every line was printed. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

for comparing two strings you should use equals instead of `==` operator. like `line.equals("end")`

The below code works fine:

```java
File data = new File("text.txt");
try {

    Scanner load = new Scanner(data);

    while (load.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = load.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("end")) break;
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    load.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
```